# JavaFX. Zomm и Scroll. Активировать ScrollPane во время зума

Tags: javafx, прокрутка

У меня есть вью с кругами и линиями, а также код который зумирует содержимое моей Pane. Сейчас я хочу добавить возможность использовать полосу прокрутки во время зума. 
Я добавила ScrollPane, но пока что полосу можно прокручивать только тогда, когда ты уменьшаешь само окно. А если окно изначального размера то прокручивать  нельзя.

Так как я в JavaFx да и в программировании в общем не большой специалист, я не могу сообразить какие свойства ScrollPane мне менять в haldler-e, когда я зумлю.

```
public void setSceneEvents(final Scene scene) {
        //handles mouse scrolling
        scene.setOnScroll(
                new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                        double zoomFactor = 1.05;
                        double deltaY = event.getDeltaY(); // Gets the vertical scroll amount
                        if (deltaY < 0){
                            zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
                        }
                        pane.setScaleX(pane.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
                        pane.setScaleY(pane.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
                        event.consume(); // Marks this Event as consumed. stops its further propagation.
                    }
                });
```

Весь ко программы можно скачать здесь https://github.com/dutkaD/lines_and_circles

Вот мой вью

```
public class Zoomable {

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    final ScrollPane scrollable = new ScrollPane();

    public double windowWidth = ValuesForView.windowWidth;
    public double windowHeight = ValuesForView.windowHeight;

    public Zoomable (Stage stage){
        show(stage, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        scrollable.setContent(pane);
        scrollable.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        scrollable.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    }

    public void show(Stage stage, double windowWidth, double windowHeight) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollable, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        setSceneEvents(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Circles and Lines");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void addCircleToPane(double x, double y) {
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        circle1.setCenterX(x);
        circle1.setCenterY(y);
        circle1.setRadius(4);
        circle1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle1);
    }
    public void addLineToPane(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        Path path = new Path();
        Line line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        pane.getChildren().add(line);

    }

    public void setSceneEvents(final Scene scene) {
        //handles mouse scrolling
        scene.setOnScroll(
                new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                        double zoomFactor = 1.05;
                        double deltaY = event.getDeltaY(); // Gets the vertical scroll amount
                        if (deltaY < 0){
                            zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
                        }
                        pane.setScaleX(pane.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
                        pane.setScaleY(pane.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
                        event.consume(); // Marks this Event as consumed. stops its further propagation.
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
public Zoomable (Stage stage){
    show(stage, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    scrollable.setContent(pane);
    scrollable.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    scrollable.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
 }
```

на

```
public Zoomable (Stage stage){
    show(stage, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    scrollable.setContent(new javafx.scene.Group(pane));
}
```